# Date format pattern in JSP

Tags: jsp, date, localization, jstl

How to change `fmt:formatDate` pattern dynamically. I have two patterns for two locales. Also I have the property file for each locale with the date.format key, somewhere it's value is `MM/dd/YYYY`, somewhere `DD/MM/YYYY` and so on. In the JSP I have the following tag:

```jsp
<fmt:formatDate value="${news.creationDate}" pattern="<tag:resource key="date.format"/>"
```

Where `tag:resource` is my own tag, which gives resources from property file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't nest tags, but you can assign the value to a variable and pass that along.

```
<c:set var="dateFormat"><tag:resource key="date.format" /></c:set>

<fmt:formatDate value="${news.creationDate}" pattern="${dateFormat}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```jsp
<fmt:setLocale value="en"/>
<fmt:setBundle basename="com.package.Example" var="lang"/>
<c:set var="pattern"><fmt:message key="date.format" bundle="${lang}"/></c:set>
<fmt:formatDate value="${news.creationDate}" pattern="${pattern}"/>
```